# Duplicating motionpaths(keyframes)

Tags: objects, keyframes, meta-objects

I am kind of new to this whole blender program, and I'm currently trying to make a text animation where the letters are made out metaballs.

[image]

By now I have made 850 metaballs and I'm not even done with a single letter, I was wondering if there was any way to copy the or duplicate the metaballs and in some way make my work easier?

The way I'm doing is most likely the slowest.

Answer (score 2):

How about some **Particles**?

Create a single Metaball.
On a separate layer create the text and convert it to mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>)

[image]
[image]

On the text object add a particle system.

[image]

Set the **Physics** tab to No and in the **Render** tab  set it to Object and choose your metaball.

[image]

Go back to the layer with the metaball and you should have your text made of metaballs.

[image]

To see a preview of the particle system press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

You can edit the number, size, randomnes on the particle settings, and to really have fun: enable physics and get wild...